# How to configure native python logging library with logstash and elastic?

Tags: python, logging, logstash, elastic-stack

I'm new to the ELK stack and am trying to learn how to configure the native python logging function to update my Elastic DB with the help of LogStash. The resources I've found haven't been too clear to me, and I was wondering if anyone on here could help me with the basic steps. Am I on the right track in starting with these couple steps?

1. Setup of Config File for LogStash
2. Retrieve a 'logger' [logging.getLogger()] and add a Logstash Handler to it where the host is the Elastic DB URL?
3. Next steps?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use [python-logstash](https://github.com/vklochan/python-logstash) module.

Its usage is documented in the [README](https://github.com/vklochan/python-logstash#usage).

```
import logging
import logstash
import sys

host = 'localhost'

test_logger = logging.getLogger('python-logstash-logger')
test_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
test_logger.addHandler(logstash.LogstashHandler(host, 5959, version=1))
# test_logger.addHandler(logstash.TCPLogstashHandler(host, 5959, version=1))

test_logger.error('python-logstash: test logstash error message.')
test_logger.info('python-logstash: test logstash info message.')
test_logger.warning('python-logstash: test logstash warning message.')
```

Comment: Is there something for kibana?

Comment: @Amanda What do you mean "for Kibana" ? Kibana is the Web interface to request Elastic Search, you don't send logs to Kibana...